# Nested structure with python `dict` looks like "include self"

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've tried to use the following class to make a "list" of nodes which could contain nested nodes of the same type as `dict` items:

```
$ ipython
Python 3.5.3 (default, Aug 19 2017, 03:39:05) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: class value_dict_pair():
...: 
...:     def __init__(self, value=None, data={}):
...:         self.data = data
...:         self.value = value
...:
```

Make a default initialized instance: w/ `value` as `None` and empty `dict` in `data`:

```
In [2]: p=value_dict_pair()

In [3]: p.data
Out[3]: {}
```

Ok, it is really empty. Going to add another default initialized instance of `value_dict_pair` class to the `some` key of the first "node":

```
In [4]: p.data['some']=value_dict_pair()

In [5]: p.data
Out[5]: {'some': <__main__.value_dict_pair at 0x7f5c030b2c18>}

In [6]: p.data['some']
Out[6]: <__main__.value_dict_pair at 0x7f5c030b2c18>
```

Ok, now `p.data` has the only key `some` initialized with `value_dict_pair` instance. But,

```
In [7]: p.data['some'].data
Out[7]: {'some': <__main__.value_dict_pair at 0x7f5c030b2c18>}
```

**why the "nested" instance also has the `some` key??**
(yeah, looking to the `0x7f5c030b2c18` address **that is the same instance**)

```
In [8]: p.data['some'].data['some']
Out[8]: <__main__.value_dict_pair at 0x7f5c030b2c18>

In [9]: p.data['some'].data['some'].data
Out[9]: {'some': <__main__.value_dict_pair at 0x7f5c030b2c18>}

In [10]: p.data['some'].data['some'].data['some']
Out[10]: <__main__.value_dict_pair at 0x7f5c030b2c18>
```

... and so on.

What I didn't get is how adding **another** (supposed) default initialized `value_dict_pair` instance could lead to that (cycle referenced `dict`)???

Comment: Let me know if the dupe doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Yeah, it really is